# How does hook_theme() work?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook, drupal-templates

I am having a hard time understanding what [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) does.

My understanding is that it has something to do with making it possible to override templates.

I was looking at:

```
  $theme_hooks = array(
    'poll_vote' => array(
      'template' => 'poll-vote',
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
    'poll_choices' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
    'poll_results' => array(
      'template' => 'poll-results',
      'variables' => array('raw_title' => NULL, 'results' => NULL, 'votes' => NULL, 'raw_links' => NULL, 'block' => NULL, 'nid' => NULL, 'vote' => NULL),
    ),
    'poll_bar' => array(
      'template' => 'poll-bar',
      'variables' => array('title' => NULL, 'votes' => NULL, 'total_votes' => NULL, 'vote' => NULL, 'block' => NULL),
    ),
  );
```

Could you provide an example of how it works?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It provides a place for a module to define *its* themes, which can then be overridden by any other module/theme. It will also provide the opportunity for any module to use a hook such as `mymodule_preprocess_theme_name` to change the variables passed to the eventual theme function or template file.

There are basically two ways to initialise a theme function:

```
theme('poll_results', array('raw_title' => 'title', 'results' => $results, etc...));
```

and

```
$build = array(
  '#theme' => 'poll_results',
  '#raw_title' => 'title',
  '#results' => $results,
  etc...
); // Note the '#' at the beginning of the argument name, this tells Drupal's `render` function that this is an argument, not a child element that needs to be rendered.

$content = render($build); // Exact equivalent of calling the previous example now that you have a render array.
```

Please keep in mind, you should avoid calling theme() directly (per the documentation in theme.inc) since it:

- Circumvents caching.
- Circumvents defaults of types defined in hook_element_info(), including attached assets
- Circumvents the pre_render and post_render stages.
- Circumvents JavaScript states information.

In Drupal 8, theme() is a private function, _theme(). For more detail, please see [www.drupal.org/node/2173655](http://www.drupal.org/node/2173655).

When you compare the two of these to the `poll_results` element in the example you give above you can probably work out what's happening...since PHP is not a strongly typed language Drupal is providing 'named arguments' through either a keyed array passed to the `theme` function, or as hashed keys in a render array.

As far as 'render element' is concerned, this basically tells the theme system that this theme function will be called using a render array, with *one* named argument (in this case `form`). The code would look something like this:

```
$build = array(
  '#theme' => 'poll_choices',
  '#form' => $form
);
```

This will pass whatever's in the `$form` variable to the theme function as it's sole argument.

Regarding the `template` key:

```
'poll_vote' => array(
  'template' => 'poll-vote',
  'render element' => 'form',
)
```

defines a theme called `poll_vote` which uses a template file (hence the `template` key) with a name of 'poll-vote.tpl.php' (this is by convention). The path to that template file will be found by using the path to the module that implements it (e.g. modules/poll/poll-vote.tpl.php), so it's fine to put template files in sub-folders of the main module folder.

There are two ways to actually return the output for a theme function, by implementing the physical function name (in this case it would be `theme_poll_vote`) or by using a template file. If the `template` key is empty Drupal will assume you've implemented a physical function and will try to call it.

Template files are preferable if you have a fair bit of HTML to output for a theme, or you simply don't like writing HTML in strings inside PHP (personally I don't). In either case though, the variables passed when you call the theme (either using `theme()` or a render array as described above) are themselves passed through to the template file or theme function. So:

```
function theme_poll_results(&$vars) {
  $raw_title = $vars['raw_title'];
  $results = $vars['results'];
  // etc...
}
```

If you were using a template file instead for the same method the variables would be available as `$raw_title`, `$results`, etc, as Drupal runs `extract` on the `$vars` before parsing the template file.

I'm sure there's a lot I've missed out here but if you have any more specific questions ask away and I'll try to help out.

Comment: "If you were using a template file instead for the same method the variables would be available as $raw_title, $results, etc, as Drupal runs extract on the $vars before parsing the template file." A little golden bit of information, this. Thanks.

Comment: @Clive is choosing render() instead of theme() prevent the caching and javascript potential problems u have mentionned?

Answer (score 3):

#### Drupal 6

I was stuck all day with this and now successfully implemented, so sharing my finding here, may it will help understand `hook_theme`.

There are 3 steps involved:

1. `hook_theme`

   ```
   function YOURMODULENAME_theme() {
     return array(
       'xxx_xxx' => array(
       'template' => 'xxx-xxx', // define xxx-xxx.tpl.php inside module
       'arguments' => array('xxx' => null), //define $xxx so it will available in your xxx-xxx.tpl.php
       ),
     );
   }
   ```
2. `echo`/`return` the theme in your `.tpl` or any `.module`

   ```
   $output = theme('xxx_xxx', $xxx);
   ```
3. Now variable are magically available in you `xxx-xxx.tpl.php`.

   ```
   <?php echo $xxx ?>
   ```

Note: you can pass $xxx as array,object or anything :)

Comment: This helps me a lot. Thank you verymuch. +1 for you. :)

Comment: i don't think the hook theme is well defined:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12987731/1384237

Answer (score 0):

There is yet another way: (can be found in Bartik theme)

The scenario here is that we have created our own module and want to override the default output for let's say a node with title 'zzz' only.
We don't know and don't really care how the default output is generated. All we need is to tell Drupal to use our own custom template file (node--custom--name.tpl.php) to render that specific node.

These are the steps:

1. Tell Drupal where our template file lives. (Keep in mind that this function will take effect only once and after clearing Drupal's cache):

   ```
   // Implements hook_theme()
   function mymodulename_theme() { 
     $theme = array();
     $theme['node__custom__name'] = array(
       'render element' => 'node',
       'template' => 'path_from_mymodule_root/node__custom__name',
       );
     return $theme;
   }
   ```
2. Tell Drupal where and when to use it

   ```
   //Implements hook_preprocess_node()
   function mymodulename_preprocess_node($vars) {
       if($vars['node']->title == 'zzzz') {
           $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__custom__name';
           ... your other code ...
        }
    }
   ```

   Now Drupal will use our template file for that specific case only, provided that 'node--custom--name.tpl.php' file is in the declared path, otherwise it will keep searching according to the suggestions naming conventions for a fallback template.