# Drupal : Create variable from custom .module to custom .tpl.php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I create a custom module and I want use the complete_url of my future website in the template who used/created by my module.

I tried several ways and searched Google but I don't find a solution.
However this issue seems very simply, that became me crazy x)

So, I must create a variable in my .module and add her when I return the array in the main_socialtag_theme function. Where/How can I do that ?

My .module:

```
function main_socialtag_block_info(){
    $block['main_socialtag']=array(
        'info' => t('Main socialtag'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );
    return $block;
}

function main_socialtag_theme(){    
    return array(
        'main_socialtag_block' => array(
            'template' => 'theme/main_socialtag_block',
            'variables' => array(),
        ),
    );
}

function main_socialtag_block_view($delta=''){
    if ($delta == 'main_socialtag'){    
        return array(
            'subject' => '',
            'content' => array(
                '#theme' => 'main_socialtag_block',
            )   
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks for help, and sorry for my bad english writing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to add, modify and call variables. Check [variable_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) and [variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7).

To add or modify a variable value:

```
variable_set("my_variable_name", "value");
```

To retrieve the value:

```
$myVal = variable_get("my_variable_name", "");
```

For `hook_theme` Implementation, kindly check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12985689).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Muhammad =) this way works perfectly (I keep this x) ), but this isn't the best practice way no ?
It's not possible to declare a variable in my custom module and pass her when I return the array of _theme function ? (the line : "'variables' => array()," )

Comment: What exactly you need to achieve?

Comment: Your solution is good for my probleme. Now, i'm just looking for the best practice and I think (but, maybe I mistake) the better is to pass the variable via this line "variables' => array()," (function _theme).

Comment: Are you looking for how to implement `hook_theme`?

Comment: Yes I looked, but I don't find any example who show how pass a sample variable from custom module to custom template. (Drupal 7)

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/12985689 I have also added the link to my answer.

Comment: I see your another solution :p It work like a charme, thank you very much Muhammad ! I use a modulename_preprocess function =)